# Android querying for contacts returns same number twice?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

In the past, the below code got all contacts on a phone sucessfully. However, on Android 6.0, it now gets all contacts, twice, sequentially. which is not what I want.

```
ArrayList<PersonalContact> allContacts = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor personalContacts = getContext().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

    if (personalContacts != null && personalContacts.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            String name = personalContacts.getString(personalContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String number = personalContacts.getString(personalContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            //This if statement is my current hack-y fix to this.
            if(allContacts.size() < 1 || !allContacts.get(allContacts.size() - 1).getRawPhoneNumber().equals(number))
                allContacts.add(new PersonalContact(name, number));
        }
        while (personalContacts.moveToNext());
    }

    if (personalContacts != null)
        personalContacts.close();

    return allContacts;
```

How do I only get each contact one time?

Answer (score 1):

A simple and better solution will be to just use a hashmap to remove Duplicates

```
    ArrayList<PersonalContact> allContacts = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor personalContacts = getContext().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

    if (personalContacts != null && personalContacts.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            String name = personalContacts.getString(personalContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String number = personalContacts.getString(personalContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

  String normalizedNumber = number.replaceAll(" ","").replaceAll("-", "");
            if(duplicates.get(normalizedNumber))
                return;
            duplicates.put(normalizedNumber,true);


            allContacts.add(new PersonalContact(name, number));
        }
        while (personalContacts.moveToNext());
    }

    if (personalContacts != null)
        personalContacts.close();

    return allContacts;
```